# What is the JavaScript API for drawing to a screen or canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

In the past, when programming in JavaScript, I have used Khan Academy's flavor of `Processing.js`. Over there, drawing is incredibility simple:

```
fill(0x00, 0x00, 0xFF);
rect(10, 10, 50, 45);
```

I have done little programming with vanilla JavaScript, so I have a very poor understanding of how it acts with HTML (beyond the fact that using the `<script>` tags is where the JS code goes), and what the various "standard" APIs for graphics and user input.

Comment: What do you mean by without any HTML? The `<canvas>` API expects to interact with an HTML element that is rendered in a browser. Are you creating a JS game outside of a browser environment? If so, you can't use canvas. Also, being offline has nothing to do with HTML. You can create HTML pages that run locally while you have no Internet connection. Even a pure JS game (in a browser) will need to create and modify HTML, even if you don't do it traditionally in a `.html` file.

Comment: You can use an offscreen canvas https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OffscreenCanvas  that does not require the DOM or HTML. Support is limited, and not all the context's are fully implemented yet. Because they are independent of the DOM you can also use them in  workers giving a multi threaded option to rendering. V8 has limited support so systems based on V8 will have a canvas to render on.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you mean by "without any HTML". Canvas is an HTML element, so there's always going to be some HTML involved somehow. Even if you're accessing the DOM directly through JavaScript, you need an HTML page as your "mounting" point, and as a vehicle to load your JS code.

If you don't want to write a page containing the canvas, you could append it to the page at the beginning of your application, like in the snippet below.

```js
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var c2d = canvas.getContext("2d");

document.body.appendChild(canvas);

c2d.fillStyle = "rgb(164, 228, 252)";
c2d.fillRect(0,0,20,20);
```